# Retrofit callback on main thread

Tags: android, retrofit

With a call like :

```
@GET("/user/{id}/data")
void getUserData(@Path("id") int id, Callback<Data> cb);
```

Callback is supposed to be executed on the main thread (if not using RxJava). My questions are :

1. Where does the parsing happen (let's assume I am using an XML converter for process response). Is this main thread, or a different one ? Does it depend on converter implementation ?
2. If I have to include some (heavy) validation rule/business rules, do I need to spawn a new thread inside callable ? Or is it fine to have it done in the Callback methods ?

I am looking for ways to get data in my activity from a web-service avoiding thread-management on my own (or using other approaches like IntentService, etc.), but am afraid of using RxJava either (because of experimental support). Is there another suggested approach to deal with this problem ?

Comment: "If I have to include some (heavy) validation rule/business rules, do I need to spawn a new thread inside callable ?" -- in that case, you should not be *using* `Callback`. Remove it, have `getUserData()` return `Data`, and call `getUserData()` on a background thread, such as `doInBackground()` of an `AsyncTask`. There, you can do the rest of your work, before updating the UI on the main application thread.

Comment: @CommonsWare ; If I remove Callback, retrofit makes a synchronous web-service call, and I will get a NetworkOnMainthreadException from the activity. The other option I have is to make the retrofit web-service call from a new thread in the activity - but as I mentioned, I am avoiding thread-management in my code. I am just keen to know if Retrofit can help me handle both request and response without me having to use threads/services/handlers/async-tasks. Thanks !

Comment: "If I remove Callback, retrofit makes a synchronous web-service call, and I will get a NetworkOnMainthreadException from the activity" -- if you read my comment, I wrote "call `getUserData()` on a background thread". "I am avoiding thread-management in my code" -- IMHO, that will not prove to be an effective development approach. Using a third-party library to handle specific problems involving threads is fine; saying that you refuse to deal with threads yourself is impractical.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ah.. I see the point. I was actually looking at more sophisticated libraries like Robospice (I know it can't be compared to Retrofit); but Robospice made me somewhat more demanding (as it doesn't seem to depend on me writing the threading logic). Do you see anything wrong if I spawn thread from the Callback methods for processing Response (rather than not using Callback at all) ? At worst I want to avoid threads in activities, but can (and do) use it in the other layers like the "model" for business validation.

Comment: "Do you see anything wrong if I spawn thread from the Callback methods for processing Response (rather than not using Callback at all) ?" -- there is absolutely no point telling Retrofit to call you back on the main application thread if that's not the thread you need to do your work on.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Where does the parsing happen (let's assume I am using an XML converter for process response). Is this main thread, or a different one ? Does it depend on converter implementation ?

Always a background thread no matter the converter you use.

> If I have to include some (heavy) validation rule/business rules, do I need to spawn a new thread inside callable ? Or is it fine to have it done in the Callback methods ?

This is fairly subjective and there's a lot of ways to tackle it. The `Callback` will be executed on the main thread by default.

You can change the thread on which callbacks will be invoked by supplying a custom `Executor` to the `RestAdapter.Builder`. This will affect all services constructed by that `RestAdapter`, however, which may not be what you want.

There's nothing wrong with spawning another thread (or enqueueing on an executor) from the `Callback` if the work you want to be done can be done in parallel with updating the UI (for example, light-weight caching).

If the expensive work must be done before notifying the UI then you are better off switching the method to be synchronous (no callback) and doing the threading yourself. This way you can do expensive operations before and after the HTTP call (file i/o, caching, transforming, validating, etc.).

We currently use RxJava (of which Retrofit has experimental support) for what you are asking:

```
interface Foo {
  @GET("/")
  Observable<Foo> getFoo(String bar);
}

foo.getFoo()
  .mapMany(new ExpensiveOperationFunction())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(new Observer<TransformedFoo>() { .. });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I am supplying an Executor to run all callbacks in a different pool. I am using EventBus to post it back to main thread when done. Everything seems good now, but I was curious why would I need to pass 2 Executors in the setExecutor() method (of RestAdapter.Builder) - can I pass null for the httpExecutor (assuming I am fine with the default). What if I pass the same executor for both httpExecutor and callbackExecutor ?

Comment: As per the docs, passing null for the second (callback) executor will invoke the callback on the same thread that ran the HTTP request. You cannot pass null for the HTTP executor.

Comment: ```Always a background thread no matter the converter you use.``` is this true for retrofit2 also?

Comment: @gaara87 Yes, the converter is called on OkHttp's worker thread: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/47cc621c7736cace218be341f9b480add64c9083/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/OkHttpCall.java#L106