# Retrofit2 deserialization / conversion on non-main thread using rxjava

Tags: multithreading, jackson, rx-java, retrofit2, cold-start

I've referred to [this answer already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21664833/584140) and it seems to be related to Retrofit v1.

Goal ->
To reduce cold start time by making ObjectMapper work on non-main thread. [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzoKf.png) shows a stack trace of it happening on the main thread.

Setup:

```
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.1.0"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0"
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.9'
```

This is configuration for retrofit

```
.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
.addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(ObjectMapperFactory.getObjectMapper()))
```

Below is a typical example of making a network call

```
compatibilityService().isCompatible()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(response -> { ...});
```

Within the [JacksonConverterFactory](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-converters/jackson/src/main/java/retrofit2/converter/jackson/JacksonConverterFactory.java#L56) the objectmapping seems to work on the main thread.

**What is the solution without moving away from RxJava?**

Possibly related posts

- [Retrofit2.0 using with rxjava will do costly reflection in mian thread even using subscribeOn()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944198/retrofit2-0-using-with-rxjava-will-do-costly-reflection-in-mian-thread-even-usin)
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4347

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use Retrofit 1.x, but in v2 you can define return type as `Response` object ( i.e. `Observable<Response<SomeSerializableObject>>` instead of `Observable<SomeSerializableObject>` ) .. in this way, the deserialization shouldn't happen until user calls `.body()` method on it. This way, you can modify the stream through `observeOn` operator so that it deserializes on your specified Scheduler within `map` operator for example.

I can't guarantee that its possible in Retrofit 1.x as well, but you should be able to research that easily.

Comment: FYI, i'm on v2, no v1.

That is interesting, can you provide the code which suggests, "the deserialization shouldn't happen until user calls .body() method on it"

Comment: Oh, I am sorry.. I saw your first sentence and came to conclusion that you are using v1 :) I'll write up some example and edit my answer

Comment: okay, this answer is invalid .. When writing the example, I checked the implementation and it is not lazy as I have previously thought..